# Select a HostName with Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

There are some addresses as follows :

```
http://rs320tl.rapidshare.com/files/119371167/sth.rar
```

I'm gonna select `rs320tl.rapidshare.com` with Regex, but I'm not familiar with Regular Expressions. 
Would you please guide me ?

Thanks.

PS.
`rs320tl` in the address is variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to go down the Regex/C# route, I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
string sOriginalUrl = "http://rs320tl.rapidshare.com/files/119371167/sth.rar";
string sPattern = "http://(?'host'[0-9a-zA-Z-.]*)/.*";
Regex re = new Regex(sPattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
string sHost = re.Match(sOriginalUrl).Groups["host"].Value;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not use regular expressions to do this.

Instead, use the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(yourString, UriKind.Absolute);
string host = uri.Host;
```

If you want to check whether the string is acutally a URL, use the following code:

```
Uri uri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(yourString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    //String is not a valid URL.  Waah waah waah
string host = uri.Host;
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the Regex one, Would you please post a regular expression to do that.

Comment: Are you sure! it selects whole of the address!

Comment: You need to use the capture group.

Answer (score 1):

"//(\w.*?\w)/" group[1] will have your url

Comment: Are you sure about the expression! I wanted to test it, I receive this error `Unrecognized escape sequence` for `w`

Comment: You need to put an `@` before the string.